# Powershell Import-VM from folder, not from XML file

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v

I have exported a VM I have created on Hyper-V manager on Windows 10.
The result is a folder with machine, snapshot, and hdd files.

I now have to import this VM on a core server 2019, through powershell.

However, the Import-VM cmdlet demands a XML file as input, something that I seem to recall Hyper-V manager previously produced upon export.

Am I missing something here? Is there a different cmdlet I should use, or perhaps the export is supposed to still produce that XML file and for some reason I am not getting it?

Thanks

Comment: If I was able to help you, could you please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on `v` under the answer's score. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Essentially every Hyper-V Virtual Machine has at least one file. It is its configuration file. And it is always stored in XML format.

You could find this file for a VM you exported under `Virtual Machines` folder.

You could either import it in place or have more options. Look at the docs [there](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/import-vm?view=win10-ps)

> **Example 1**
>
> ```
> PS C:\> Import-VM -Path 'D:\Test\VirtualMachines\5AE40946-3A98-428E-8C83-081A3C6BD18C.XML'
> ```
>
> Imports the virtual machine from its configuration file. The virtual machine is registered in-place, so its files are not copied.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell now imports the .VMCX file, as there is no longer an XML file for each VM.

```
Import-VM -Path 'C:\<vm export path>\2B91FEB3-F1E0-4FFF-B8BE-29CED892A95A.vmcx'
```

[Import-VM from docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/import-vm?view=win10-ps)

Below is one way to import all files from a folder (and register in-place, so that the VM files are not copied) using PowerShell:
cd to the folder containing the .VMCX files. Then:

```
dir *.vmcx -name | Import-VM
```